# Couldn't parse file content

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I ran my Python code, I got the error message below.  Can anyone help?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yangjy/PycharmProjects/mmi_anti_pytorch-master/language_model/lm.py", line 8, in <module>
    import tensor
  File "/home/yangjy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensor/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from tensor import service
  File "/home/yangjy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensor/service.py", line 14, in <module>
    from tensor.protocol import riemann
  File "/home/yangjy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensor/protocol/riemann.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tensor.ihateprotobuf import proto_pb2
  File "/home/yangjy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensor/ihateprotobuf/proto_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    serialized_pb=b'\n\x0bproto.proto\"\x81\x01\n\x05State\x12\x0c\n\x04time\x18\x01 \x01(\x03\x12\r\n\x05state\x18\x02 \x01(\t\x12\x0f\n\x07service\x18\x03 \x01(\t\x12\x0c\n\x04host\x18\x04 \x01(\t\x12\x13\n\x0b\x64\x65scription\x18\x05 \x01(\t\x12\x0c\n\x04once\x18\x06 \x01(\x08\x12\x0c\n\x04tags\x18\x07 \x03(\t\x12\x0b\n\x03ttl\x18\x08 \x01(\x02\"\xce\x01\n\x05\x45vent\x12\x0c\n\x04time\x18\x01 \x01(\x03\x12\r\n\x05state\x18\x02 \x01(\t\x12\x0f\n\x07service\x18\x03 \x01(\t\x12\x0c\n\x04host\x18\x04 \x01(\t\x12\x13\n\x0b\x64\x65scription\x18\x05 \x01(\t\x12\x0c\n\x04tags\x18\x07 \x03(\t\x12\x0b\n\x03ttl\x18\x08 \x01(\x02\x12\x1e\n\nattributes\x18\t \x03(\x0b\x32\n.Attribute\x12\x15\n\rmetric_sint64\x18\r \x01(\x12\x12\x10\n\x08metric_d\x18\x0e \x01(\x01\x12\x10\n\x08metric_f\x18\x0f \x01(\x02\"\x17\n\x05Query\x12\x0e\n\x06unicodeing\x18\x01 \x01(\t\"g\n\x03Msg\x12\n\n\x02ok\x18\x02 \x01(\x08\x12\r\n\x05\x65rror\x18\x03 \x01(\t\x12\x16\n\x06states\x18\x04 \x03(\x0b\x32\x06.State\x12\x15\n\x05query\x18\x05 \x01(\x0b\x32\x06.Query\x12\x16\n\x06\x65vents\x18\x06 \x03(\x0b\x32\x06.Event\"\'\n\tAttribute\x12\x0b\n\x03key\x18\x01 \x02(\t\x12\r\n\x05value\x18\x02 \x01(\tB\x1a\n\x11\x63om.aphyr.riemannB\x05Proto')
  File "/home/yangjy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 878, in __new__
    return _message.default_pool.AddSerializedFile(serialized_pb)
TypeError: Couldn't parse file content!
```

Comment: look for any spaces in between file path

Comment: @Rose can you please provide some sample code for that ??

Comment: My code is edited by python2, but I used python3 interpreter to run. I met some problems, I converted the source codes style from python2 to python3 using python3's rules, and later found out that the code was wrong and I didn't know how to change it. Maybe I should use python2 interpreter to run my code.

Comment: @Rose, was issue resolved if not could you provide sample code to reproduce the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, finally I found that's my source proto file importing wrong proto files.

After referring to the right files, it is fixed.

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "tensorflow/path_to_correct_files/file1.proto";
import "tensorflow/path_to_correct_files/file1.proto";
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I messed up the property index of my message, like this:

```protobuf
message Request {
  bool prop1 = 1;
  bool prop2 = 2;
  bool prop3 = 3;

  bool prop4 = 2;     // WRONG! should be 4
  string prop4 = 3;   // WRONG! should be 5
}
```